# How to stop match at first occurence of a match on each line?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to stop pattern match at very first occurence of multiple strings

Below are the strings i want to match using A-Z|0-9_A-Z

```
248_HIGH_FAN_BLADE,
67B_COOLER_BLADE,
BLADE_LOW_DIM
```

```regex
[A-Z|0-9\_A-Z](.*?)
```

I would like to match 8_H in first string,B_C in second string, E_L in third string only .No other matches should be shown. I am trying on regex101 website using php and implement in R

Comment: [A-Z|0-9\_A-Z](.*?)  regex i have used

Comment: So what exactly are these objects in R? Is this a vector of character values? I think you want something more like `[A-Z|0-9]\_[A-Z]` for your regular expression. It would be better to show the code you are actually running to test this.

Comment: What is the expected output? Just extract these substrings? Or replace? Try `(?m)^.*?\K[0-9A-Z]_[0-9A-Z]`

Comment: Why the `(.*?)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it worked perfectly !!!..can you please explain "(?m)^.*?\K" part of the regex? i would like to match these and group them using a value in new column of df eg 'product type' ='Normal" if this match occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^.*?\K[0-9A-Z]_[0-9A-Z]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYMOKz/1)

[R matching code](https://ideone.com/sGpFFP):

```
x <- "248_HIGH_FAN_BLADE,\n67B_COOLER_BLADE,\nBLADE_LOW_DIM"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?m)^.*?\\K[0-9A-Z]_[0-9A-Z]", x, perl=TRUE))
# => [[1]]
# => [1] "8_H" "B_C" "E_L"
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier making `^` match start of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[0-9A-Z]` - a uppercase letter / digit
- `_` - underscore
- `[0-9A-Z]` - an uppercase letter / digit

You may use a `stringr` regex based solution, too:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(x, "(?m)^.*?([0-9A-Z]_[0-9A-Z])")[[1]][,2]
# => [1] "8_H" "B_C" "E_L"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using stringr:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(c("248_HIGH_FAN_BLADE", "67B_COOLER_BLADE", "BLADE_LOW_DIM"), pattern = "[0-9A-Z]\\_[A-Z]" )
```

Answer (score 0):

To match that pattern you might use a capturing group and capture a single `[A-Z0-9]`, then `_` and then a single `[A-Z0-9]`:

```
\b[A-Z0-9]+([A-Z0-9]_[A-Z0-9])
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary (Or use anchor `^` to assert the start of the string)
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times A-Z or 0-9
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[A-Z0-9]_[A-Z0-9]` Match 1 time A-Z0-9, then `_` and again one times A-Z0-9
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWPvU0/3) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/idhOBf)

For example

```
library(stringr)
string = "248_HIGH_FAN_BLADE"
pattern = "\\b[A-Z0-9]+([A-Z0-9]_[A-Z0-9])";
str_match_all(string, pattern)[[1]][,2]
```

Result

```
[1] "8_H"
```

Comment: @A380 The matches before do not really matter if you can use capturing groups to get the  values that you want which are highlighted in green on regex101.